# Can't integrate facebook comments to blogger

Tags: integration, href, blogger, facebook-comments

Error:

> The comments plugin requires an href parameter.

But that's not true.

I have followed about 5 tutorials, carefully step by step, and it always give me this error.

I change the html tag, then Include the JavaScript SDK, changing & for & or using provided code by tutorial and meta tags, and then place the code
 `<div class="fb-comments" expr:data-href="data:post.url" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>` 
below `<data:post.body/>`, i tried other places too but made no difference.

No diference if i use `expr:data-href="data:post.url"` or `data-href="data:post.url"` or `data-href="http://mycustomdomain.com"` or `data-href="http://mybloggerdomain.blogspot.com"`
or those cases with `href=` or `url=`

App is carefully configured and rechecked. I tried create new apps.

The tutorials i have followed are new, not even 30 days old.

I have no idea of what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please paste a link to an example you followed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I tried this, just for curiosity and works:

```
<fb:comments href='data:blog.url'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
<div class='fb-comments' data-num-posts='20' data-width='470' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
```

this solved the problem for me

[click here for a detailed blog post on this](http://howwesolvedit.blogspot.in/2012/02/integrating-facebook-comments-plugin.html#!http://howwesolvedit.blogspot.com/2012/02/integrating-facebook-comments-plugin.html)